# How to avoid input search field to be searched in html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed the search in html page, and I am facing an issue. When I am going to search some field in search bar, input field is also searched in html page. I need to avoid input field to be searched in html page.

Below is my html.

```
   <form>
        <input type="text" id="search"  placeholder="Enter your search term..." name="searchString">
        <button type="submit" id="searchbutton">Search</button>
   </form>
```

the screenshot of searched term. I have searched "is" in the input search field.

[image]

This is the similar code which i have develop and here something is mention which is I am not able to apply in my code.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

Notes from the page:

> Some browsers (e.g. Firefox 2.0 and newer) the window.find() method may find and highlight not only the existing text on the page but also the user's input text in forms, including the search box itself. To avoid this incompatibility, in the above example we have not included the `<input>` tag defining the search box in the HTML code of the current page; instead, we load the search box via an IFRAME element. The content in any FRAME or IFRAME is not directly accessible via the current window object, and therefore cannot be found with window.find().